# Can you find a topological homotopy given two spaces' singular chain complexes are chain homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I understand that a homotopy equivalence between two spaces induces a chain homotopy on simplicial homotopy groups $h:C_n(X)\rightarrow C_{n+1}(Y)$, however I was unsure about the converse. Ie given $h:C_n(X)\rightarrow C_{n+1}(Y)$ chain homotopy, is it true that $X \simeq Y$ (homotopic)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converse is not true. Even when chain complexes are chain homotopy equivalent by a chain map that is not induced from a continuous map.

When two chain complexes have isomorphic homologies, then they are homotopy equivalent (see this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10974/does-homology-detect-chain-homotopy-equivalence ). You didn't specify coefficients so I presume it is $\mathbb{Z}$. I don't think this is true for arbitrary coefficients, but should be true for any principal ideal domain. Also homologies are typically easier to work with than chain complexes, that's why I use them here.

So all you have to do is to find any two spaces with isomorphic homologies, but not homotopy equivalent, e.g. a point and double comb.